# What are the differences between vector store retriever invoke() and getRelevantDocuments()?

Tags: langchain, langchain-js

Here are the code snippet,

```js
const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(embeddings, {
  pineconeIndex,
});
const retriever = vectorStore.asRetriever();

// what are the differences between invoke() and getRelevantDocuments?
await retriever.invoke("How to make a cake?");
await retriever.getRelevantDocuments("How to make a cake?");
```

I seem to have difficulty to search from the API reference that describe these two functions. Do you know when should we use `invoke()` and `getRelevantDocuments`?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, calling `await retriever.invoke("How to make a cake?")` and `await retriever.getRelevantDocuments("How to make a cake?")` have the same result, but the two methods belong to different interfaces.

#### getRelevantDocuments()

`getRelevantDocuments()` belongs to the `BaseRetrieverInterface`, which `VectorStoreRetriever` implements. `vectorStore.asRetriever()` returns a `VectorStoreRetriever` instance (a subclass of `BaseRetriever`).

You can call `getRelevantDocuments()` directly if your use case utilizes **ONLY** the retriever.

References

1. [BaseRetrieverInterface (GitHub)](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchainjs/blob/main/langchain-core/src/retrievers.ts#L26)
2. [BaseRetriever.getRelevantDocuments() (GitHub)](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchainjs/blob/main/langchain-core/src/retrievers.ts#L89)

#### invoke()

`invoke()` belongs to the `RunnableInterface`, which `BaseRetrieverInterface` extends. The implementation of `invoke()` is in the `BaseRetriever` class. The current implementation (`0.1.28`) of `invoke()` calls `getRelevantDocuments()` directly.

```js
async invoke(
  input: string,
  options?: RunnableConfig
): Promise<DocumentInterface<Metadata>[]> {
  return this.getRelevantDocuments(input, ensureConfig(options));
}
```

So why are both `invoke()` and `getRelevantDocuments()` needed? `invoke()` is needed because the chain abstraction in LangChain is arbitrary with respect to which runnable abstractions (prompt templates, retrievers, models, output parsers, etc) exist in a chain.

For example, a chain can be composed of a retriever and a model. In order to maintain a common API that can be called to run the chain, each runnable abstraction (retriever and model) should have the `invoke()` method. Another chain can be composed of a model and an output parser. For the same reasons as before, each runnable abstraction (model and output parser) should have the `invoke()` method.

If your use case requires a chain, call `invoke()`.

References

1. [RunnableInterface (GitHub)](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchainjs/blob/main/langchain-core/src/runnables/types.ts#L32)
2. [BaseRetriever.invoke() (GitHub)](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchainjs/blob/main/langchain-core/src/retrievers.ts#L72)